# Creating world files for a batch of aerial photos

Tags: georeferencing, aerial-photography, world-file

I am looking for a way to geolocate a bunch of aerial photos by creating a world file per photo. The photos are taken in the same orientation and from the same altitude. 
The work flow would be to create one world file with the correct first 4 lines of code giving the correct rotation and scale. And then to calculate all the top left corner points for all the photos via a formula.

To create a world file for a aerial photo it first needs to be correctly referenced. I thought of referencing 1 photo and then making copies of the world file for all the othe photos. Except after I georeferenced the first photo and exported the first world file I realized the gps point of the world file is not on the top left corner of the photo, instead it is slightly off to the side, this is because the photo was rotated so the program used the top left corner of the geotiff where there is no photo data just a black triangle. I cannot use these values form the world file because the reference is off.

Is there a way of exporting a world file by first specifying where the gps point will be and that the top left pixel of the photo will also be on that point or a formula that calculates lines 1,2,3 and 4 of the world file for me?

Comment: Aerial photos (raw frames) need to be orthorectified https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthophoto not just georeferenced. What software do you have available? Do you also have the camera files? Did you take these photos from a drone? Do you have a DEM?